# Is ASP.NET AJAX for script controls obsolete too?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-4.0

I've been developing some script controls in server-side with their client-side counterpart.

Since I've found some articles and Stakoverflow questions regarding that Microsoft has practically deprecated ASP.NET AJAX Client Library in favor of jQuery, I'm worried about if developing script controls is also obsolete.

I find useful OOP Microsoft AJAX's API and its integration with server controls.

Finally, I'm currently using ASP.NET 4.0.

Thank you in advance.

---

**CONCLUSION:**

*My project is using ScriptControls and Callback API. Inside ScriptControls I've been always using jQuery instead of AJAX Client Library. In other words, I believe that I don't have a hard dependency on what's meant to be obsolete in .NET future versions.

Current scenario is .NET 5.0 is far enough and current version, 4.0, has these ASP.NET features and, for now, there are the official approaches provided by ASP.NET.

Since .NET 4.0 will be in the market as the latest version for some time yet, and I doubt Microsoft could completely remove ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 features in 5.0, I believe both ScriptControls and Callbacks will be safe for the next 5 years, and this is enough for me.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but ScriptControls+Callback API+jQuery (for DOM manipulation) should be safe and a good way for the medium/long run.*

Comment: if you don't have any problems using jquery , try to move to that as you have more suport for jquery now.

Comment: @kobe but jQuery doesn't cover some features like server-side control integration. Will I need to implement my own taylored client-server integration? I'm not going to move to ASP.NET MVC, I need Web Forms because my solution needs a component-oriented architecture.

Comment: Note: I couldn't be able to review answers until tomorrow morning GMT+1, sorry. I'll read everyone tomorrow. I appreciate your support in advance!

Comment: I've been investigating more in this way and I found this library: http://ajaxoop.org/ Maybe you'll find it useful in order to have MS AJAX OOP features without MS AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in all fairness, JQuery is the way forward now. For existing projects, it can be pretty painful to make the shift, and if things work well as they are, I don't see why it needs to be changed anyways.

But if you are starting anything new, and if it is going to survive for a while (as all software does), then you are better off with JQuery, since it will keep evolving over time and you can keep reaping those benefits.

Plus if there was ever a time to learn JQuery, it's now. Might as well dive head-on.

Comment: It's not a problem of jQuery or not jQuery. I know jQuery and I'm using it for this project, but jQuery doesn't integrate with server controls out-of-the box, you know :D

Comment: Actually I've never heard about this project, I'll take a look. I believe your answer is fine for me, because it clears my mind about this problem. I only need to migrate script controls to jQuery, but ScriptManager features like callbacks and so, can remain "as is" because I find them useful and it works like a charm in my scenario. I'll prefer to leave this answer not marked as the right one because I want to listen more opinions, but I've upvoted it. If tomorrow it remains as the most clear answer, I'll mark it, don't doubt it :) Thank you for your support.

Comment: I've reviewed DJ, it seems interesting. I'll look forward for professional projects as it seems to be stable enough for that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Microsoft stopped supporting LINQ to SQL a long time ago in favour of Entity Framework but people are still using LINQ to SQL.

Whilst it is true that Microsoft is no longer putting effort into developing MS AJAX library any further, the judgment call for me on whether to use it or not is if the target developers know it better than another JavaScript library (assuming that time to get things done is an important factor).

If you're starting from an equal standpoint, I'd probably go with jQuery because it's supported by Microsoft and there is a large community that can help with issues, it's under continuous active development and it will help if you decided to move parts of the application to ASP.NET MVC, which plays very nicely with jQuery.

Comment: But, f.e. what about ScriptManager. Is this going to be deprecated someway too?

Comment: I don't *think* it would be deprecated as it is an integral part of MS AJAX, UpdatePanels, generating proxies for calling webservices etc. I think it's safe to assume that it won't have any further development on it.

Comment: Good to know and an important point. This was my concern as I'm using such some ScriptManager features that are extremly useful. I've upvoted this comment and your answer. Why don't you add this info to the answer? I find it useful for others.